# Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I want to make prediction of suicide rate (log_suicides_per_100k) in R using random forest, the problem I have is that when I try to pick one level of a variable, I get the error:

```
Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

The model is:

```
rf3 <- randomForest(log_suicides_per_100k~ age+sex+log_gdp_per_capita+log_population+year, # formula data = train, # data ntree = 500)
```

sex has four levels: male and female
age has six levels; "15-24 years", "25-34 years", "35-54 years",
"5-14 years", "55-74 years", "75+ years"

```
structure(list(year = c(2001L, 2004L, 2008L, 2010L, 2004L, 2011L
), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), age = structure(c(1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("15-24 years", "25-34 years", "35-54 years", 
"5-14 years", "55-74 years", "75+ years"), class = "factor"), 
log_population = c(14.0462476055718, 10.0651811415341, 
13.5550389013841, 
10.2665669441479, 15.5047227728237, 13.4021140795298), 
log_suicides_per_100k = c(2.42657107277504, 
4.03069453514564, 2.38508631450579, 4.15261347034608, 
2.88480071284671, 
0.647103242058539), log_gdp_per_capita = c(7.67786350067821, 
9.13701670755734, 11.1338150021447, 9.65117262392164, 
7.95472333449791, 
8.14177220465645)), row.names = c(7888L, 8465L, 7593L, 8535L, 
25159L, 9656L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to predict the suicide rate for males in the group age 75+ for the year 2025.

```
prediction <- predict(rf3, data.frame (age = '75+ years', sex= 'male', log_gdp_per_capita = 13.082, log_population = 9.393, year = 2025))
```

Comment: You have put "gender" instead of "sex" in your prediction data frame.

Comment: I rectified it. Thank you! But still getting the same error

Comment: Please dont add your data as an image; can you edit your question with `dput(head(train))`; this will allow us to see if the levels are as expected i.e. any unexpected whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that works. Because you haven't included all your code, there is a risk that it will not work for you. The factors and levels need to match up so this is the key thing to get right. The factors and levels in the training data are copied and set to match those in the test data.

```
library(randomForest)

traindf <- structure(
    list(
        year = c(2001L, 2004L, 2008L, 2010L, 2004L, 2011L),
        sex = structure(
            c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L),
            .Label = c("female",
                                 "male"),
            class = "factor"
        ),
        age = structure(
            c(1L, 6L, 3L, 6L,
                2L, 3L),
            .Label = c(
                "15-24 years",
                "25-34 years",
                "35-54 years",
                "5-14 years",
                "55-74 years",
                "75+ years"
            ),
            class = "factor"
        ),
        log_population = c(
            14.0462476055718,
            10.0651811415341,
            13.5550389013841,
            10.2665669441479,
            15.5047227728237,
            13.4021140795298
        ),
        log_suicides_per_100k = c(
            2.42657107277504,
            4.03069453514564,
            2.38508631450579,
            4.15261347034608,
            2.88480071284671,
            0.647103242058539
        ),
        log_gdp_per_capita = c(
            7.67786350067821,
            9.13701670755734,
            11.1338150021447,
            9.65117262392164,
            7.95472333449791,
            8.14177220465645
        )
    ),
    row.names = c(7888L, 8465L, 7593L, 8535L,
                                25159L, 9656L),
    class = "data.frame"
)

rf3 <- randomForest(log_suicides_per_100k ~ age+sex+log_gdp_per_capita+log_population+year, data=traindf)

testdf <- data.frame(age='75+ years', sex='male', log_gdp_per_capita=13.082, log_population=9.393, year=2025)
testdf$sex <- factor(testdf$sex, levels=levels(traindf$sex))
testdf$age <- factor(testdf$age, levels=levels(traindf$age))

prediction <- predict(rf3, testdf)
prediction

#3.200609
```

Comment: Hopefully this helps... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer